# Programación Web con un enfoque en la seguridad

Tags: php, javascript, html5, ajax

Saludos amigos que todo lo saben!
Ando programando en entorno web y casi siempre tengo esta costumbre:

```
<div tabindex="-1" role="menu" aria-hidden="true" class="dropdown-menu" style="">
  <button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item" id="button-INICIAL-5-MAÑANA-A-primary" onclick="fLoadAgreedAreas(this.id)">Turno MAÑANA, Sección A</button>
  <button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item" id="button-INICIAL-5-MAÑANA-B-primary" onclick="fLoadAgreedAreas(this.id)">Turno MAÑANA, Sección B</button>
  <button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item" id="button-INICIAL-5-TARDE-A-primary" onclick="fLoadAgreedAreas(this.id)">Turno TARDE, Sección A</button>
</div>
```

En el ID de los elementos suelo colocar variables que paso a javascript y manipularlos, incluso cuando están en el lado del cliente (javascript) los vuelvo a enviar al servidor mediante petición AJAX.

Por ejemplo, cuando en una tabla se cargan los datos de una persona, siempre se añade un boton de modificar, ese botón lleva como ID el id_persona para así con javascript enviar al servidor para modificar los datos de la persona correcta. Algo similar a mi codigo de arriba.

El problema surge cuando un atacante ve el código fuente de la página y modifica el valor de los ids de los elementos y probablemente enviar comandos de sql injection, etc.

Pregunto.
¿Mi forma de programar es correcta? Es decir, al enviar valores del servidor a javascript
¿Se puede cifrar/ofuscar el codigo html y javascript que son los visibles para un usuario?

Comment: respuesta rapida: no... respuesta mas rapida: tu back end debe siempre desconfiar de lo que recibe, asi que hay que volver a chequear absolutamente todo de vuelta, como si todos los datos estuvieran mal... las validaciones del lado del cliente, son solo para hacerle la vida mas simple al usuario...

Comment: no? entonces cómo debo enviar información del servidor al cliente? en el caso de cargar personas en una tabla, cómo estar seguro de que se está editando la persona correcta? Yo lo hago poniendo el id_persona en el id del boton (modificar)

Comment: No es la forma de enviar los datos del servidor al cliente, sino lo que el servidor recibe del cliente. En PHP debes validar que `id_persona` existe y que el usuario en sesión tiene los permisos adecuados para modificar, ya sea porque tiene rol de administrador o está modificando su propio registro.

Comment: Hola. @gbianchi tiene absoluta razón. Por favor consulta [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/91033) en la respuesta que ofrece A.Cedano está todo lo que necesitas saber.

Comment: En el lado del servidor siempre valido los datos que envia el cliente, asi como el usuario que tenga los permisos adecuados. 
A lo que me voy es si en un boton editar lleva como id "perosna_35", en javascript en algunos casos paso por ajax y por ende 35 lo almacenaria en una variable de javascript, como id_persona = 35, en el servidor no bastaría con preguntar si id_persona existe o si es entero ya que si al acceder al codigo fuente ese 35 lo cambio por 40 u otro número, pasaria facilmente el filtro en PHP y por consiguiente actualizaría los datos de la persona con ID 40 y no 35 como se pens

Comment: hay alguna forma de codificar el id, clases de los elementos y en el lado del servidor descodificarlos?
Cuando veo el codigo fuente de facebook, las clases estan codificadas. ¿cómo lo hace Mark Zuckerberg?

Comment: Cuando dices _"ya que si al acceder al codigo fuente ese 35 lo cambio por 40 u otro número, pasaria facilmente el filtro en PHP"_ estás dejando claro que no realizas las validaciones correspondientes al **procesar los datos** y parece que solo _lo intentas_ al mostrarlos.

Comment: @Triby, cómo validarias id_persona en el lado del servidor? Yo pergunto primero si existe un envio por post, luego verifico que id_persona no sea  0 y que tambien sea entero. pero como en el cliente ese 35 es visible, un atacante podría cambiar a 40 u otro numero y así modificar a otra persona en la base de datos. Cómo validarias del lado del servidor, ya que 35 o 40 u otro numero entero pasaria mis filtros aplicados.

Comment: No es tan complicado si cumples con estos 3 pasos: 1. Existe el dato en POST y es válido (debes sanear y verificar tipo, longitud, etc.) 2. Realizas consulta a base de datos para confirmar que el elemento existe 3. **Revisas permisos:** El usuario en sesión tiene rol de administrador o es propietario del elemento que se va a modificar o eliminar